# How to Stay DRY in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django url for users to change their password, which looks like this:

```
url(r'^change-password$', views.user_change_password, name='change_password'),  
url(r'^change-password/done/$', views.user_changed_password, name='password_changed')
```

Where `views.user_change_password` is:

```
def user_change_password(request):
    response = password_change(request,
                           template_name=r"Foo/Account/change_password.html",  
                           post_change_redirect=reverse('Foo:password_changed'))
    return response
```

This works, but it seems to me that having to specify the lookup name `password_changed` in two separate places violates the principle of DRY.

Is there a standard way in Django of dealing with this?

Comment: To me, this looks very much like `def myfunc(...)` and `x = myfunc()`, ie: you're defining something and then using it. I'm not sure how much DRYer it can get...

Comment: I could make it DRYer by defining it as a constant somewhere else, and then using that in both places. I'm new to Django though, so I was wondering if there's a standard way.

Comment: @Batman, so `foo = 'foo'; bar = foo` is not DRY, but somehow `baz = 'foo'; foo = baz; bar = baz` is?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what's happening in `urls.py`. That is where the route named `password_changed` is _defined_.

Comment: I get that part. I guess the thing that seems a bit WET to me is that if I decided that I wanted to change the name of the route then I have to rename it in a couple of places.

Comment: You'd have to rename it in one place; you'd then have to update all the places where you had referenced it to the new name. You could potentially have a set of URL name constants, so you were only defining the names once... but then what would happen if you wanted to change one of the constants? The names of the routes are already a DRY abstraction for the URL itself, so ideally you will not change the names very often if at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is pretty much the standard way of doing it. At least from what I gather in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

It seems that defining the names as strings is what throws you off. My understanding is that it allows interesting uses like namespacing, transparent use across templates and views and saving you from `import`ing everywhere you use it.

As @Chris points out, what you're doing in `urls.py` is *defining* the url name, and then in views and templates you *use* it.

You could probably add more levels of indirection by defining:

```
my_url_name = 'password_changed'
```

but I don't see how that is DRYer. When reversing the url resolution, you'd need:

```
reverse('Foo:' + my_url_name)
```

which isn't much nicer.

In short, think of it as a variable name in quotes. If you need to rename it, you'll have the exact same problem as when renaming a variable.